# Which SPSS method should I use to conduct my analysis?

Tags: anova, spss, contrasts

I am new statistics and I need to describe a study and then do some analyses using SPSS. I have two groups and I want to ask a dichotomous categorical question, then provide further information and ask the question again. I want to be able to know 1) what difference the new information has provided to answers in the second question (i.e change in choice from q1 to q2), and 2) whether this is dependent on which group the respondents are in.

I am really unsure about what kind of tests I would do, although I think there would be a contrast for question 2?

I hope I have described this clearly, I have a great deal of difficulty with anything numerical and I would be very grateful for any help.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to test is whether the propensity to respond in a given way is the same before and after the information provision, then a simple McNemar test would seem appropriate. That's available under Nonparametric Statistics for related samples in SPSS. In Version 27.0.1, there's also a new procedure for handling proportions that includes options for comparing paired proportions. It's on Analyze>Compare Means>Paired-Samples Proportions.